# What is the reputation range for people who have careers profile? Any rough Ideas?

Tags: discussion, reputation, jobs, profile-page

I have got a couple of invitations from Stack Overflow to create a profile on careers and frankly speaking I am desperate to create one. But looking at my reputation I don't think I have enough to showcase something on my careers profile. I want to create a profile but at the same time I don't want to get lost there among the people who are much better than me something like below guys.

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/dystroy

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/Oded

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/spolsky (Exceptional Case, I am not comparing myself with him :) )

So I want to know what is the general range, as to where do the people on careers lie who have say 5K Stackoverflow reps.

Thanks Much

Comment: Keep in mind most of those really top people don't need to use the careers site to get a job.

Comment: 3k rep is nothing to sneeze at. There is no "must have this much rep" before creating a profile. In the same way that there is no rule for when you can write a CV...

Comment: As for how much rep (or other qualifications) you need to have for any particular job poster to notice you, that will vary greatly between jobs.  The better the job, the higher their standards will be.

Comment: @servy Not necessarily.  Having a high rep doesn't make one well connected or particularly well suited to find a job in a new city or country.  It can, however, help you be noticed.  Both your SO and Careers profiles help in this regard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have people with no Stack Overflow presence at all, under 500 rep, or tens of thousands rep.

To understand how employers view rep, it's best to think of your strength on particular tags/technologies rather than the highest overall rep.

Employers often have very narrow specifications for what they are looking for in a developer. So someone with a 50k rep who only answers javascript and python questions may not impress them as much as the user with 3k rep who has great answers in the java-ee tag if that's what they're looking for.

The key is having a full profile, Stack Overflow answers and otherwise, in order to rank high in search results and communicate fully with the employer while they decide who to move through the process.

People with 5k SO reps are well suited for Careers 2.0 given they build an interesting and complete profile.