# What percentage of Stack Overflow users have a Careers 2.0 profile?

Tags: support, status-completed, jobs, users

Does anybody know the approximate ratio of Careers 2.0 profiles to Stack Overflow users? Or where that information could be located?

Comment: Active users only? All users? Minimum rep?

Comment: @Oded all users..thanks for response

Comment: Not sure whether this is public information. Also, who cares really? Is there a specific situation that makes you want to know?

Comment: yeah but I got some useful related information to my question [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158629/what-is-the-reputation-range-for-people-who-have-careers-profile-any-rough-idea/158644#158644) By knowing ratio, I can imagine the competition. As I guess SO has 17M user who are competing to give quality answer

Comment: my mistake not all 17M

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [blurb page for Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/about) says

> Currently there are 77,485 candidates interested in being contacted

The [reputation leagues for Stack Overflow](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow) says

> ```
> Total Reputation
> Total Rep     Users
> 200+          112,262
> 1+            1,438,992
> ```

So somewhere between 5% and 69%, depending on what you want to count as a user.

Comment: Your second link is helpful...thanks @AkashM

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure this is meaningful. I have a Careers 2.0 profile, but I have near 0 interest in changing jobs.